# What is the fastest way to searching through an array of a thousand of unknown objects

Tags: php, arrays, dataset

I am working on a product search system for an eCommerce app, where Here I have my product objects stored in an array. Now, I want to be able to search through those products and find all product that belongs to a certain category.
I have tried using foreach loop, but this doesn't seem to be efficient enough, considering the the execution time and the number of products it has to loop through. Which is the best way to do this?
Here's what I Have done:

```
public function sortByCategory( $category )
{
    foreach ( $this->products as $product ) {
        if ( $category == $product->getCategory() ) {
            $this->result[] = $product;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My preference would be to let your database take care of sorting. Since it can enhance query caching (natively) you won't have to go through your results after fetching.

Comment: ^^ What he said ^^ and where does `$products` come from in that code?

Comment: And I am not seeing any actual SORTing going on. I think you would be better to call it **filtering** or **searching**

Comment: This function is doing the same as a 'where' condition in an sql string (if it comes from database)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have already retrieved the products and saved them in a session which is then assigned to the products variable, by so doing I won't have to go to the database each time a product is searched for.

Comment: But you will have to go to the **file system** which is almost definitely a slower retrieval mechanism and will miss any amendments made to the database made during the session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching an unstructured/unordered collection will always be at least `O(n)` as each element needs to be visited.   If it's somehow already sorted you might be able to figure out a more optimal algorithm, but trying to sort in code first manually, you'll already be at `O(n log n)` time before even doing the search!

However, any tricks you can do to lower the overhead on subsequent searches/access is what you should look for.

Learn, Love, and Leverage the magic of hash tables (in php this is associative array's)!!!!  They'll help you solve many problems in your coding career!

Just iteratate through the products once them and store them in an associative array of arrays by category name:

```
  $grouped = [];

   foreach ( $products as $product ) {
        $cat = $product->getCategory();
        !empty($grouped[$cat])?:$grouped[$cat] = []; 
        $grouped[$cat][] = $product;
   }
```

Then you grab a specific category by name:

```
  $result = $grouped['SomeCategoryName'];
```

Since the products are objects, the sub-array in the `$grouped` associtative array are just array's of references--not duplicates--so most likely won't incur major space hit.

Finally, it's only `O(n)` to do this grouping, you only perform it once, and retrieval from then on is `O(1)`.

Comment: I think you also got confused by the OP's title. OP is **searching** not sorting

Comment: Ah... yup, changing my answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Better answer? :)

Comment: I sincerely appreciate everyone of you wonderful people for your response and contributions to this question from over a year ago. All your answers and contributions were awesome and insightful, and they helped me find my way. Thanks a million.